# How to programmatically turn off IE's Protected Mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, registry

I am rookie in C# and I am creating an Automation Tool using Selenium Webdriver. I want to programmatically change the Protected Mode settings in IE using c#.

Can anyone help me on this with your suggestions.

Also is it possible to programmatically update the registry to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
        };

       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(path to the driver.exe", options)
        {
            /*
             * open the supplied URL on the opened instance of the browser
            */
            Url = "your url to open"
        };
```